# Custom ports broke apache

Tags: networking, apache2, apache2.4

I wanted Apache (v2.4.41) to listen to port 802 and 44302 instead of 80 and 443 on my Ubuntu (v20.04) server so I did the following:

- Edited the port numbers in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`. Now the file has just two lines and looks like this:

  ```
  Listen 802
  Listen 44302
  ```
- Edited the port number in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` like this:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:802>
    ....
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Edited the port number in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` like this:

  ```
  <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:44302>
      ....
    </VirtualHost>
  </IfModule>
  ```
- Edited the port number in the other virtual hosts inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available` as well.
- Restarted apache
- Confirmed apache is listening to the new ports by using `netstat` as well as `lsof` and got the following:

**netstat:**

```
tcp6       0      0 :::44302         :::*            LISTEN      113959/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::802           :::*            LISTEN      113959/apache2
```

**lsof -i:802**

```
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2 113959     root    4u  IPv6 3543809823      0t0  TCP *:802 (LISTEN)
apache2 113960 www-data    4u  IPv6 3543809823      0t0  TCP *:802 (LISTEN)
apache2 113961 www-data    4u  IPv6 3543809823      0t0  TCP *:802 (LISTEN)
```

**lsof -i:44302**

```
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
apache2 117939     root    6u  IPv6 3547650042      0t0  TCP *:44302 (LISTEN)
apache2 117940 www-data    6u  IPv6 3547650042      0t0  TCP *:44302 (LISTEN)
apache2 117941 www-data    6u  IPv6 3547650042      0t0  TCP *:44302 (LISTEN)
```

- Confirmed nothing else is listening port 80 and 443 by using both `netstat` and `lsof`.

---

Now when I try to access any of the websites or even the server ip address (with :802 or :44302), I simply get a `This site can’t be reached` error.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

### UPDATE:

I rebooted the server instead of just restarting apache just now and `https://example.com:44302` is working now but `http://example.com:802` still returns the `This site can’t be reached` error.

No changes were made to the configuration above except for the server reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason port 44302 works but port 802 didn't was because port 44302 is in the range of opened ports in Firewall, while 802 is not.

Ports 0 - 1023 are considered privileged ports and are restricted to the root user unlike the rest of the ports.

Switching the port from 802 to a general port 80 alternative like 8080 fixed the problem.